# ruby-Selenium Web-Driver to manipulate objects on a canvas

Tags: ruby, selenium, fabricjs

I am using Selenium through Ruby to test a page which contains a Canvas (which uses fabricjs to handle objects on the canvas) and manipulate objects on the canvas. The objects, however, are not distinct page-elements. Only the Canvas is. Here is my current relevant code:

```
act = driver.action #driver is the Selenium webdriver object
act.click_and_hold(canvas1).move_by(0, -30).release.perform
sleep(3) #For visual inspection to ensure that both steps run
act.move_to(canvas1, 155, 155).click_and_hold.move_by(-10, 0).release.perform
```

The problem is that click_and_hold operates on the page-element beneath the "mouse", not its actual position. As a result, my click_and_hold actions always start from the center of the canvas, not the object I want to move / resize / rotate.
Is there another feasible method using Selenium to achieve the same goal?
Would another gem enable a normally non-feasible method? 
Is there a way to identify the object in the page's Fabricjs and run its relevant Javascript to modify it?

Comment: If the Selenium driver does not expose the desired functionality, you can use JS: `driver.execute_script "console.log('OK')"`